# minikube cannot increase ingress client-max-body-size

Tags: minikube, nginx-ingress

In dev mode, I created a local cluster, following https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/
Everything work fine, but when post a body with big size I get 413 Request Entity Too Large from nginx.
This is my ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/large_client_header_buffers: "100m"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/body-size: "100m"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "100m" 
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: "100m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-max-body-size: "100m"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "100m"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffers: "100m"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy_max_temp_file_size : "100m"

spec:
  rules:
    - host: mydomain
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client
                port:
                  number: 80
  tls:
    -
      hosts:
        - mydomain
      secretName: my-tls-secret
```

Comment: Can you try the workarounds discussed though this [document](https://imti.co/413-request-entity-too-large/#:~:text=The%20%E2%80%9C413%20Request%20Entity%20Too,adjust%20in%20the%20Nginx%20configuration)

Comment: yes, i tried all these suggestions but without luck.